# check a vps guest memory usage and CPU usage

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, memory-usage, libvirt, utilities

I have vps guests that are managed by KVM and libvirt. Using virt-df, I am able to check the real disk usage of each vps guest.

```
#virt-df [--options] -d domname
```

Is there a similar utility tool to check memory usage and cpu usage?

I tried virt-top, but the cpu% and mem% it returned were mostly less than 1%, which was less accurate.

Answer (score 4):

```
 virsh dommemstat <vm-name>
```

This will show the currect memory the vm is using, along with the total memory allotted to it.

Example: My vm name is testvm.
so the command will be:

```
 virsh dommemstat testvm
```

Output:

```
 actual 8388608
 swap_in 189132507715
 rss 1945288
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're confusing things here.  virt-df will show you the disk space inside the guest.  virt-top will show you what resources the guest is using on the host.  The 'less then 1%' you refer to indicates the guest was not using very much of the host's resources.

There is no way to tell from outside a KVM instance what processes are running, or what percentage of CPU/memory they are using.  KVM instances are basically a black box as far as the host is concerned.

Comment: "virsh dommemstat [name]" returns the actual memory a vm is using.